# Symbol Technologies LS2208 USB barcode scanner not working with Raspberry Pi 2 WINDOWS 10 core IOT

Tags: raspberry-pi, windows-10-preview

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B, my scanner doesn't work in Windows 10 Core IOT.

When I focus a textbox and scan a barcode, nothing happens. I also tried added KeyDown event for the textbox, so that I see in debugger when a key is pressed. The USB keyboard works, but scanning does not. 
How can I enable this barcode scanner ?

Comment: Does it have drivers?

Comment: im not sure if barcode scanner needs a  driver, they are only a keyboard.

Comment: I tryed windows 7, windows 8.1, windows 10. LS2208 just works like  plug and play. Maybe i have to install drivers on windows 10 core IOT, but I don't know few things about windows 10 core IOT : (what, how, why, where).

Comment: That might be cause the OS pulls in the appropriate drivers, and windows 10 core IOT may not have ports

Comment: It might. But Theoretically i could port drivers myself ? Is that hard to do ? Any tutorial in mind ?

Answer (score 0):

So I found this another guy on a Random google page with Raspberry Pi 1.0, and he suggests that I first insert scanner into PC running windows, then into Raspberry pi 2.0 And so I did that. And it worked. But the trick is, that I plugged in USB into booted Pi. If I boot Pi with USB scanner inserted, nothing happens(scanner does not work).

After insertion, I Run remote debugging with Visual Studio 2015 RC, and suddenly my TextBox start to work with the scanner ! That is awesome ;) I also notice, that If I boot Raspberry Pi 2.0 with scanner inserted in USB, it does not work. So i have to reinsert it each boot :(